# Как вытащить имя папки и записать его в xml файл?

Tags: xml, bat, powershell

Ситуация: в директории лежит xml файл (Load.xml) и еще одна папка (Project), в которой лежит 1 папка с неизвестным названием. Как с помошью bat файла вытащить имя папки, найти в Load.xml подстроку и заменить ее на имя папки?
UPD. Текст Load.xml, заменить нужно ProjectName:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects Server="127.0.0.1" Password="7319" MinPeriod="200">
  <Project Name="ProjectName" Address="1"/>
</Projects>
```

Comment: На powershell сделать это будет намного проще.

Comment: как это сделать с помощью powershell?

Comment: Вы начните, мы подскажем.

Comment: А чего начать? Какие команды гуглить, чтобы например вытащить имя неизвестной папки?

Comment: Команды batch: **dir**, **forfiles**, **for**, **findstr**, **if**. На powershell- **Get-ChildItem**, **Get-Content** и т.д. Думаю, решение на Powershell - будет намного технологичнее.

Comment: С xml нужно работать именно как с xml, а не как со строкой. Поэтому, не нужно находить подстроки, а нужно находить элементы/атрибуты xml. Покажите, как выглядит ваш xml-файл и куда нужно вставить имя папки.

Comment: Я понял должно получится нечто такое: 
$name = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\Project\' -Name
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content Load.xml
$myXML.Projects.Project.Name = $name[0]
$myXML.Save("Load.xml")

Comment: Но выводится ошибка Не удается задать "Name", так как только строки могут использоваться в качестве значений для задания свойств XmlNode.
Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил с помощью скрипта powershell:

```
$name = @(Get-ChildItem -Path '.\Project\' -Name)
[xml]$myXML = Get-Content .\Load.xml
$myXML.Projects.Project.Name = "$name"
$myXML.Save('Load.xml')
```